# How to change Symfony's console script name

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-flex

I just installed fresh copy of stable Symfony 4 as follows:

```
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton .
```

**I would like to rename the console script name** though from `bin/console` to `bin/symfony`. How to do that? If I just rename it, after `composer install` I get an error:

> Script cache:clear returned with error code 1
>
> !!  Could not open input file: bin/console

Obviously this comes from the post install script:

```
"scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
        "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
        "assets:install --symlink --relative %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
    },
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ],
```

How to make this work properly? I already checked [how to override Symfony's default structure](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/override_dir_structure.html), but found nothing related.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your error is related to Symfony Flex. If you specify "symfony-cmd" it will look for "bin/console". But it is just a shortcut and you can change it to the following:

```
"scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
        "bin/symfony cache:clear": "script",
        "bin/symfony assets:install --symlink --relative %PUBLIC_DIR%": "script"
    }
}
```